# Changing Interface Orientation for BW::Media Modal in RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I have a RubyMotion application that is completely portrait (no landscape), but loads `BW::Media.play_modal` for an external MP4 video URL that I'd like to play in landscape mode.

It's loaded like this using RMQ, PM, and BW:

```
def on_load
  rmq(@object).on(:tap) do
    BW::Media.play_modal(@object.video_url)
  end
end
```

I know how to enable `autoRotate` for an entire screen/controller, but is there a way to *force* landscape mode only when the modal is played?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem-

1. I enabled `landscape_left` and `landscape_right` throughout the RM app.
2. I set the `should_autorotate` method to `false` throughout the app.
3. I added a condition using PM's `modal?` method that set `should_autorotate` to true when a modal was active.
4. I used RMQ's `rmq.orientation.landscape?` method to set the view back to portrait as soon as the modal was exited.

I hope this helps if anyone else has the same problem!